# Angular: whether the current route or page is protected or guard actice

Tags: angular, routes, initialization, angular-router-guards

I am using Angular 9 and I would like to know is there a possibility to check whether the current page is protected/guarded or not during APP_INITIALIZER phase.

I am using the APP_INITIALIZER to set some pre-configuration for the app but during this process I have to know whether the current route/path/page is protected. The route can be of lazy-module and this route or routes is/are not available in the `this.router.config`.

Currently, working solution, is to read all the routes recursively and then create a list of all routes available in app and them match the current route path within list, which is pretty bad solution to me. I am looking for a correct way to implement this solution.

Please help,

Thanks in advance,

*Always available for the more info if needed.*

**EDIT**: Adding an example

Suppose I have a list of routes:

```
App-routing.modules.ts

[
  {path: '', component: XY},
  {path: 'profile', component: Profile},
  {path: 'submodule', load: LoadSubModule},
  {path: '..', load: LoadSubModule2, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {path: '..', load: LoadSubModule3},
]



LoadSubModule routing module
[
   {path: '', component: yz},
   {path: 'form', component: Form, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
   {path: 'subSubModule', load: LoadSubSubModule, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
]
```

If I land on the page `domain.com/submodule/form/` I want to know that the route `/submodule/form` is guard or not while `App_Initilizer` is being done.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of routes declared in your router with this

```js
constructor(private router: Router) {
  console.log(this.router.config);
}
```

You'll get all the routes defined within your current router, as well as their paths, components, guards, etc.

You can then use a recursive function to check for all routes having a guard.

Comment: Thanks but I forget to mention the sub-modules / lazy modules. Routes of lazy modules are not shown in the router.config

Comment: For that, create a service providedIn root, hat you inject into every module, which will do this for you.